# Set browser in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, browser

Thunderbird is opening links in Chrome and I want it to use Firefox.

Following [this](https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-default-browser-in-thunderbird-2532751), I set the values to true, but then don't receive the popup window in Step 5, it just goes to Chrome.

What to do?

Thunderbird 115.3.1(64-bit)
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reflection of your 'Default Browser' in Ubuntu Settings > Default Applications.

On my installation of Ubuntu 22.04 links from Thunderbird open in whatever browser is selected as the *default* application for web at this place.